# Pinch zoom ImageView - Want to scale whole image beyond size of screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview

I have pinch zooming for an image, however when I first load the app the whole of the image is not visible, only a portion. The image fills the width of the screen but there is white-space above and below it. Also when the image is scaled the image becomes very short. The aspect ratio should stay the same.

I would like to have the whole image visible when the app loads and then I want to be able to zoom out with two fingers where the image doesn't become smaller than the size of the screen, so that the screen is always full (the image is a map).

For zooming in, the image should scale beyond the width and height of the phone screen. That way I can pan across to view the map in detail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Related code is below.

My MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private MapView image;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    float mLastTouchX, mPosX;
    float mLastTouchY, mPosY;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1f;

    private int mActivePointerId = MotionEvent.INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.save();

        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
                final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
                final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);

                // Remember where we started (for dragging)
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
                mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, 0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
                final int pointerIndex =
                        MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(event, mActivePointerId);

                final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
                final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);

                // Calculate the distance moved
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                mActivePointerId = MotionEvent.INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            {
                mActivePointerId = MotionEvent.INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            {
                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
                final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, pointerIndex);

                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId)
                {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        image.setX(mPosX);
        image.setY(mPosY);

        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            matrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            image.setImageMatrix(matrix);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Custom ImageView:

```
public class MapView extends ImageView
{
    public MapView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void scaleImage(int boundBoxInDp)
    {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        float xScale = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / width;
        float yScale = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / height;
        float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);
        width = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
        height = scaledBitmap.getHeight();

        // Apply the scaled bitmap
        setImageDrawable(result);

        // Now change ImageView's dimensions to match the scaled image
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private int dpToPx(Context c, int dp)
    {
        float density = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return Math.round((float)dp * density);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        final Drawable d = this.getDrawable();

        if (d != null)
        {
            // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
            final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            final int height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth());
            this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.kilobolt.framework.locationfinder.MapView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/uea" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different approach to solve the problem of displaying a custom map. Instead of displaying a fixed sized image, I used Google Maps Javascript API v3 (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).

I displayed this in a web view and created a reusable function in javascript to create custom markers.

If anyone comes across this issue, which appears to not to be well documented, give this map solution a try, and feel free to message me. Hope this helps.